# Switch использование readonly переменных в case

Tags: c#, типы-данных

Имею следующий код

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value = "value1";
            // switch с const переменными работает
            switch(value)
            {
                case ConstVariable.VALUE1:
                    Console.WriteLine(ConstVariable.VALUE1);
                    break;
                case ConstVariable.VALUE2:
                    Console.WriteLine(ConstVariable.VALUE2);
                    break;
                case ConstVariable.VALUE3:
                    Console.WriteLine(ConstVariable.VALUE3);
                    break;
            }

            // ЗДЕСЬ ОШИБКА!!! switch c readonly переменными не работает
            switch (value)
            {
                case ReadOnlyVariable.VALUE1:
                    Console.WriteLine(ConstVariable.VALUE1);
                    break;
                case ReadOnlyVariable.VALUE2:
                    Console.WriteLine(ConstVariable.VALUE2);
                    break;
                case ReadOnlyVariable.VALUE3:
                    Console.WriteLine(ConstVariable.VALUE3);
                    break;
            }
        }


        static class ReadOnlyVariable
        {
            public static readonly string VALUE1 = "value1";

            public static readonly string VALUE2 = "value2";

            public static readonly string VALUE3 = "value3";

        }

        static class ConstVariable
        {
            public const string VALUE1 = "value1";

            public const string VALUE2 = "value2";

            public const string VALUE3 = "value3";

        }
```

В блоке switch я могу использовать переменные const, но если я использую переменны readonly, то получаю ошибку

> A constant value is expected

Почему так, разве переменные readonly на этапе компиляции не определяются?

Comment: _разве переменные readonly на этапе компиляции не определяются?_ нет не определяются

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`readonly` значит, что поле должно быть инициализировано в конструкторе и последующая модификация данного поля запрещена. Т.е. это гарантия того, что раз поле проинициализировано в конструкторе, оно больше не может быть изменено в других частях класса. Но это не делает его сущностью времени компиляции — нет, оно защищено от переинициализации, но не является константным.

Подробнее в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/acdd6hb7.aspx)